# google analytic doesn't display current user

Tags: android, google-analytics-api

I am implementing Google analytic for my app tracking in android. i follow Google document which is mention in that document but it is not display any active user in analytic dashboard. 
My code is in Application Class

```
private static GoogleAnalytics sAnalytics;
private static Tracker sTracker;

sAnalytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);


synchronized public Tracker getDefaultTracker() {
    // To enable debug logging use: adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
    if (sTracker == null) {
        sTracker = sAnalytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
    }

    return sTracker;
}
```

In Activity

```
  Tracker mTracker;
  MyAppplication application = (MyAppplication) getApplication();
    mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();


    mTracker.setScreenName("User Profile");
    mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
```

In Manifest File

```
 <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"/>

    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />
```

in global_tracker

```
 <string name="ga_trackingId" translatable="false">UA-10*******-1</string>
```

use This Gradel dependence

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.4'
```

Comment: please edit with your complete code so other's can easily help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

google anyltic is working only for old user.For new user you must have to add firbase.